# Need clarification on Packet Fragmentation in the Network Layer

Tags: tcp, network-protocols, ip-fragmentation

I do understand the purpose of the packet fragmentation. From the answer, the only thing I don't understand is the Total Length and Fragment offset. I would greatly appreciate any help you can give me in working this problem.

Below is the question and the answer.

Suppose that host A is connected to a router R 1, R 1 is connected to another router, R 2, and R 2 is connected to host B. Suppose that a TCP message that contains 900 bytes of data and 20 bytes of TCP header is passed to the IP code at host A for deliv- ery to B. Show the Total length, Identification, DF, MF, and Fragment offset fields of the IP header in each packet transmitted over the three links. Assume that link A-R1 can support a maximum frame size of 1024 bytes including a 14-byte frame header, link R1-R2 can support a maximum frame size of 512 bytes, including an 8-byte frame header, and link R2-B can support a maximum frame size of 512 bytes including a 12-byte frame header.

Answer:

```
The initial IP datagram will be fragmented into two IP datagrams at I1. No other fragmentation will occur.
Link A-R1:
Length = 940; ID = x; DF = 0; MF = 0; Offset = 0
Link R1-R2:
(1) Length = 500; ID = x; DF = 0; MF = 1; Offset = 0 
(2) Length = 460; ID = x; DF = 0; MF = 0; Offset = 60
Link R2-B:
(1) Length = 500; ID = x; DF = 0; MF = 1; Offset = 0 
(2) Length = 460; ID = x; DF = 0; MF = 0; Offset = 60
```

Answer (score 0):

This is surely an exercise at University. It's better if you try to solve it yourself instead of asking for the response.

The field values you can see them here: http://mars.netanya.ac.il/~unesco/cdrom/booklet/HTML/NETWORKING/node020.html

Please read it.

I will give you a partial response. The rest, you should solve it alone to learn.
DF means that the sender does not want to fragment. I suppose it will be always 0 in your exercise.

MF is 1, if there is another fragment following. So, if a datagram is fragmented in 2 datagrams, the first one will have it in 1 and the second one will have it in 0 because there are no additional fragments. When the destination receives fragment 1, it will know there is at least another fragment to wait for because MF is 1. When the destination receives fragment 2 before fragment 1, it will know it is part of a bigger fragmented datagram because offset is not 0 (in fragment 2 MF is 0).

In all datagrams you must consider 20 bytes (in general) for TCP layer (if TCP) and 20 Bytes for IP layer. In general in Ethernetv2 (not GbE) the MTU is 1500 octets. Then you can transmit 1480 octets maximum in the IP payload (20 Octets for IP layer header) and 1460 maximum in the TCP payload (20 octets, minimum, for IP header and 20 octets, minimum, for TCP header).

As a hint, fragmentation will occur at any hop in IPv4. In IPv6 only source node can fragment. So, in A-R1 there is not fragmentation needed.